# Writing QT app for Android without qml

Tags: android, qt

I need to write an Android application based on pure QT/C++. However, most of the tutorials on the net seem to use QML. Even QT Creator's "Quick App" generates QML-based code. I am wondering if someone can guide me into creating a simple "Hello World" Android program using just QT. Or, just point me in the right direction. Regards.

Comment: Even if you use QML for the GUI you would do the rest in C++. Who told you that you cannot use QML?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply deploy your Qt/C++ application for Android and indeed there is no need to necessarily use QML in a Qt application for Android. All you need is to set up your development environment as described [here](http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-2/) and [specifying settings for packages](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html#specifying-settings-for-packages). After that when you build your application using the specified kit for Android, the APK file is generated and it would work normal on a device.